# Merging JSON-LD results with original JSON

Tags: geojson, json-ld

I'm working on visualizing several geojson files with a large set of properties. I would like to use json-ld to add some meaning to some of these properties. I don't have a lot experience with JSON-LD, but sucessfully applied the jsonld.js to expand, compact, etc. my geojson file and @context. In doing so I noticed that the end results only returns the graph that is actually described in the context. I can understand that, but since it only represents a small part of all my properties, I have some difficulty using the results.

It would help me if I could somehow merge the results of the jsonld operation with the original geojseon file. eg:

```
"properties": {
        "<http://purl.org/dc/terms/title>": "My Title",
        "<http://purl.org/dc/terms/type>": "<http://example.com/mytype>",
        "NonJSONLDPropertyKey" : "NonJSONLDPropertyValue",
        etc.
```

I would still be able to recognize the properties with an URI, but could also work with the non-json-ld properties. Any suggestions how this might work? Or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could map all other properties to blank nodes... that is identifiers that are scoped to the document. The simplest way to do so is to add a

```
"@vocab": "_:"
```

declaration to your context.